# Is $D=\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y \in \mathbb{R} \} $ a 1d or 2d manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, geometric-topology

Suppose you have the set $D=\{(x,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{(0,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y \in \mathbb{R} \} $ with the subspace topology of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Is D a manifold?
My understanding is that for the set D to not be a manifold i have to show that there does not exist a homeomorphism $f:U \subset D \rightarrow f(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ where $f(U)$ open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

My intuition says that it is not a manifold, but what confuses me is that it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the subspace topology.

**Edit:** Can it be a 1d manifold with charts:

$f_1:(0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f_1(x)=(x,0)$
$f_2:(0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f_2(x)=(-x,0)$
$f_3:(0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f_3(y)=(0,y)$
$f_4:(0,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $f_4(y)=(0,-y)$

Thank you!

Comment: @whoisit Subspace can be though as "topological subspace". It does not always mean "linear subspace"

Comment: @Didier I think this is it. Thank you!!!

Comment: @lebong66 You're welcome. Can you then mark the question as duplicate for reference purpose?

Comment: How can i do that?

Comment: @lebong66 You should have seen a box when I first posted a comment, with "Yes, it answers my question" or "no, it doesn't" (or anything similar).

Comment: You mean "homeomorphism", not "homomorphism".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $D$ would be a manifold, it would be a $1-$dimensional manifold. In particular, if $U$ would be an open set of $D$ that contain $0$, then $U\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ would be an open set of $D$ with $4$ disjoints connected components, whereas, if it would have been a manifold, $U\setminus \{(0,0)\}$ would be an open set with at most $2$ disjoints connected components.

Comment: can you please show me an example. Thank you!!!.

Comment: Take for example $U=((-1,1)\times \{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times (-1,1))$. Then $$U\setminus \{(0,0)\}=((-1,0)\times \{0\})\cup((0,1)\times \{0\})\cup(\{0\}\times (-1,0))\cup(\{0\}\times (0,1)).$$ @lebong66

Comment: alright it can't be a 2d manifold. But can it be a 1d manifld with the charts above?

Comment: @lebong66: No, because you can't reach 0 with your parametrization. Notice that for the reason I explained above, you won't be able to parametrize locally around 0, that's why it's not a Manifold.

Comment: Your final step, claiming at most 2 disjoint connected components isn't entirely obvious to me. I guess it's using the fact that every connected $1$-manifold is homeomorphic to either $\mathbb{R}$ or $S^1$?

Comment: Rather that every $1-$manifold is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Still missing something. How does a local property imply something about connected components of the whole?

Comment: Locally in the sense that if $x\in D$, then there is a neighborhood $U\ni x$ that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Roughly speaking, every point need to have a neighborhood that is $\mathbb R$ (up to a homeomorphism). So, in your case, the only "mad point" is $0$. The reason is that for any open $U$ that contain $0$,  as far as you take out $0$, you get four disjoint connected component, and thus, it can't be homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ because, taking any point out of $\mathbb R$ will give $2$ disjoint connected component. Therefore, $0$ has no neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: However, $D\setminus \{0\}$ will indeed be a manifold (unconnected manifold, but a manifold).@aschepler

Comment: Now I'm seeing it. Though I think it's easier to prove $f(D \setminus \{0\})$ has at least four connected components than to show it has exactly four.

Comment: Also, I think a strict proof $D$ is not a $d$-manifold with $d>1$ would involve [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain). And $D$ could obviously be a manifold if using a topology other than the subspace topology imposed from $\mathbb{R}^2$, but that was explicitly stated.

Comment: @aschepler: "I think it's easier to prove (∖{0}) has at least four connected components" What is $f$ ? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: $f$ is the hypothetical homeomorphism from an open set $U$ in the subspace topology on $D$ to an open set in $\mathbb{R}$. So I should say $f(U\setminus\{0\})$.